# What use istead of createSuggestBox()?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to make text field in UI which would have functionality of autocompleting. I have prepared array for checking purposes.

I shouldn't use `createSuggestBox()` because it's deprecated.

Comment: Suggest you use "HTML Service" https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/
Also looks like a duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14252729/search-box-ui-in-apps-script  ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery auto complete with HTML service.
http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/